# RxJs subscribe works but map does not

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I have an ngrx store like this:

`export default compose(storeLogger(), combineReducers) ({
  auth: authReducer,
  users: userReducer
});`

In a service I try to do the following:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private _http: Http, private _store: Store<AppState>, private _updates$: StateUpdates<AppState>) {
     _store.select<Auth>('auth').do(_ => {console.log("token:" +_.token)});
  }
```

No operator works except subscribe. Why?

Comment: Have you imported the appropriate `rxjs/add` mixins anywhere? Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: You mean this on the top ```import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking in general why this occurs then here is an explanation by Andre Stalz on his blog.

http://staltz.com/how-to-debug-rxjs-code.html

> Because Observables are lazy until you subscribe, a subscription triggers      the operator chain to execute. If you have the console.log inside a do and no subscription, the console.log will not happen at all.

So basically this is the typical behavior of operators.
In your example you have attached a "do" operator.  With no subscription to the observable that the "do" operator returns it will not fire. Most operators won't fire until there is at least one subscription on the observable the operator returns. Map is one of those.

http://jsbin.com/bosobuj/edit?html,js,console,output

```
var source = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(3);
source.do(x=>console.log(x));

var source2 = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(5);
source2.do(x=>console.log(x)).subscribe(x=> x);
```

the output is 5 because only source2 "do" is executed.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the do or map operator will execute once for each subscription in each emit of a new value on the observable.  So if you have 3 subscriptions and a new value is emitted then the operator runs 3 times.